# How can set position dynamic textview in code?

Tags: android

I want to set position of TextView dynamically(in Java code).
I tried so:

```
public void add(View view)
{
    TextView[] tx = new TextView[3];

    FrameLayout layout;
    layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        tx[i] = new TextView(this);
        tx[i].setText("9");
        tx[i].setId(i);
        tx[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        tx[i].setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        //Here I would like set position
        layout.addView(tx[i]);
    }
}
```

In advance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

//try this code

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILLPARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout)).addView(tx[i], params);
```